# terraform V12: Error import KeyPair: MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter PublicKeyMaterial

Tags: amazon-web-services, import, terraform, public-key, key-pair

getting error "import KeyPair: MissingParameter: The request must contain the parameter PublicKeyMaterial " when I run "terraform apply". what does this error mean.

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_test_instance" {
  ami           = var.instance_test_ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  subnet_id     = var.aws_subnet_id
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name

  tags = {
    Name = var.environment_tag
    }
   provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo ${self.public_ip} > public-ip.txt"
    }
   provisioner "remote-exec" {

     connection {
        type    = "ssh"
        host    = self.public_ip
        user    = "centos"
        private_key   = file("${path.module}/my-key")
        }

    inline = [

        "sudo yum -y install wget, unzip",
        "sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk"
    ]
   }
}
```

Comment: using terraform version v12

Comment: Where is `connection` used? Can you provide complete example?

Comment: Can you edit the question and provide the example?

Comment: @Marcin I edited my question with the example. Thanks for taking a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that everything else is correct, `connection` block should be inside [provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html), not outside of it:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_test_instance" {

  ami           = var.instance_test_ami
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  subnet_id     = var.aws_subnet_id
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.deployer.key_name  


  provisioner "remote-exec" {

    connection {
      type    = "ssh"
      host    = self.public_ip
      user    = "centos"
      private_key   = file("${path.module}/my-key")
    }

    inline = [
        "sudo yum -y install wget, unzip",
        "sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk",
     ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I moved the connection inside the provisioner per your suggestion. I found that there was another "tf script" that is importing the "key" as well. it was user error. works as expected. Thanks